# Why does the Windows 10 App & Features list not know the size of every installed app?

Tags: windows-10

This is something that bothers me. I have a 1 TB SSD that I pretty much only use for games. It's currently below 100 GB in free space and I'm hoping to uninstall some games taking a lot of room. However, it only knows the size of 16 of the over 60 games installed. There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason tow what games it can detect the size of: both those with and without size are a mix of newer and older games, a mix of big budget games and small indie projects.

Why does Windows 10 not know the size of many programs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's up to the program's installer to write this information in the Registry. If it doesn't, Windows will try to guess by looking in Program Files for folders with a similar name to the program. This doesn't always work.

> If a program does not provide size information, then the Programs and
> Features control panel starts guessing by doing textual matching
> between the name of the program in the Start menu and the name of the
> program in the Programs and Features folder.
>
> And if a program does not provide installed-on information, then the
> Programs and Features control panel assumes that the file was
> installed (or last modified) the last time its uninstall information
> was modified. There is no creation time for registry keys;
> last-modified time is all you get.
>
> The final piece of the puzzle is that in Windows 10, the Storage Service looks for programs that registered with the Programs and Features control panel but didn't provide any size information, and it works behind the scenes trying to do a better job of figuring out which files on the system are part of that program, and when it comes to a conclusion, it updates the registration with the updated size information.
>
> You install a program that provides incomplete information in its Programs and Features registration.  Storage Service figures out a good estimate for the size of the program. The Storage Service then updates the registry entry with the improved size estimate.
> Updating this information causes the Size column to change.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180522-00/?p=98805

Comment: Different but working link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040709-00/?p=38493